# This Regex doesn't match things I think that it should

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a field in my web application into which the user is expected to enter one or more digits separated by one or more periods.

The following is a typical example of what the user may enter:

589327498321.43243214.32421423.

I've written the following JavaScript code to test value:

```
var uid = $(this).val();
var uidRegex = /(^\d|\.$)+/;
var isValid = uidRegex.test(uid);
```

I'm getting the wrong result.  It seems that this code tells me that the entry is valid if the user's entry *begins* with a digit or period.  How can I fix this so that the entire entry must consist exclusively of digits and periods to be valid?

Comment: So, start with a digit, allow periods and digits after the first character, no empty strings, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the pattern you're looking for is

> Number followed by any number dot + number sequences

If so try the following `/^(\d)+(\d|\.\d)+$/`

**EDIT**

OP indicated in comments that consecutive dots are legal.  Here's the updated regex to account for that as well `/^(\d)+(\d|\.)+$/`

Comment: +1: This works for me.  I believe that the problem is that I had my beginning and end of string markers nested inside the parenthesis. Thank you.

Comment: @Rice This really worked?  In that case, is the final period from the example "1423." actually just sentance ending punctuation and not part of your user's input?

Comment: @Buh, that's how I was interpreting the question.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies: You mentioned "separated by one *or more* periods". Do you mean to allow `123...45`?

Comment: I realize that my example is very simplistic and does include edge cases such as 1323...45, but I'm not particularly concerned about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(\d|\.)+$/
```

That should do it =]

Comment: This will match "abc123". You'll need to enforce the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uidRegex = /[^\d.]/;
var isValid = ! uidRegex.test(uid);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uKm7F/

---

If you want to disallow a period at the beginning of the string, use this:

```
var uidRegex = /(?:[^\d.]|^\.)/;
var isValid = ! uidRegex.test(uid);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uKm7F/6/

Comment: This will match "abc123". You'll need to enforce the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: I like the reverse thinking on this. However, it allows a beginning `.` and empty strings.

Comment: @Jonathan M - ...which can easily be solved by: `/(?:[^\d.]|^\.)/`: http://jsfiddle.net/uKm7F/6/ . I updated my answer...

Comment: Cool. That would be a good edit, per the OP spec. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider:

```
var uidRegex = /^\d+(\d|\.)+$/;
```

Comment: This allows for the input string to begin with a `.` which appears to be illegal according to the question

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern: `/^\d+(\.+\d+)*$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d[\d\.]*$/
  ^   ^--any number of digits or periods
  |-start with a digit
```

Answer (score 0):

If your field is required (and must contain at least 2 characters), this will do it:

```
/^(\d)+(\d|\.)*(\d)+$/
```